# How to follow up on late salary

Tags: communication, united-kingdom

I am not of religion that celebrate Christmas but I was told I will be paid on Christmas Eve as other for paid a week before or Christmas but it’s passed Christmas. 
How do I approach it as to my boss in email?

Comment: So, others got paid on Christmas Eve but you'll be paid later? Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: @rath yes. That is true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just ask.

> Dear boss, I was told we were getting paid on the 24th, but I haven't been - was there an oversight, or was I mistaken?

Then depending on the outcome:

- If told you should've been paid, be *relatively* firm not to be kept waiting much longer for pay - sometimes companies try to pay you next month instead because emergency payroll incurs an extra cost - unless you can afford this and are happy to allow it, make it clear that you need payment earlier
- If there's a delay, but not much of one, consider the value of being a bit flexible on this - it puts you in good stead with your boss, and basically they owe you one.
- Don't put up with anything you can't afford to .

Late payment, if it comes to that, is a breach of contract (worth noting that it's not a breach of contract until you've not been paid when your contract states you should've), and whilst you should be diplomatic, you shouldn't be a pushover.

Another thing that can be challenged in the UK is *disparity of treatment* - it makes a difference that everyone else has been paid early but you haven't.

If you haven't been paid a week after you *normally* would have been, I'd contact a solicitor.

Comment: wow _ disparity of treatment_ is a thing I didn't know. I am an expat here and my first job was dismissed exactly what is described [here](https://www.legal-island.com/articles/uk/features/hr/2016/feb/disparity-in-treatment-of-employees-and-unfair-dismissal/). Thanks for exposure to this.

Comment: Incidentally, don't call them "dear boss" :D

Comment: @cookieMonster Bear in mind with disparity of treatment cases that they are complicated in a lot of cases - there are valid reasons to treat people differently - and subject to the two year rule: you have to have been somewhere for two years before you can bring a tribunal case for unfair disparity of treatment.

Comment: @OwenC.Jones "disparity of treatment." on age sex ect  has no two year rule

Answer (score 6):

Usually you must be paid before the end of the month. It is quite possible that the people who actually move the money to your account don't work between Christmas and New Year, so to comply with the laws they have to pay before Christmas. But you have no legal right to that; if the money is in your account on Friday 28th they are legally fine.

Comment: I would think Monday 31st would also be fine, wouldn't it?

Comment: In most months, but not in December, because it is a bank holiday. The money must be available to you on a working day.

Comment: The reason I asked is I was told 2 dates that it will be paid but both passed but generally it is the last day of the month.

Answer (score 1):

I would ask some of the other people if they got their money to understand if it's just me.
I would also ask if there is a mistake or something.

Like "Hello, mr. / mrs. X, I just checked my bank account and the salary is not there yet. Can you please check on your end if there is a mistake or maybe I should wait a bit more for some reason?".

Whatever you do - do not write heart wrenching letters or mention any kind of authorities in the first email. Those are your worst options to start the conversation.

If you think your boss is not going to pay you - then maybe you can complain to the authorities asking them to check. But do not do this is a first action. Clear all other options before that.