# Discussing of raise / review

Tags: united-kingdom, performance-reviews

As per my contract I have a review/raise due this month. I believe folks are busy to not to notice it. My manager and me sit on same table, so it is open office with other folks in the room. I was mentioned to have causal chat to catch up and mention but it isn't possible.

So what is the best way (we chat or email), so it comes in time as I keen to know because financially I am tight. It is worth mentioning here that [last payment was late](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/125314/how-to-follow-up-on-late-salary).So it is done in timely manner.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere there are other people on the table, do you think I should say it infront  of them as when hired, they went out so manager and his boss can seal the deal.

Comment: I think @jesse's answer is the most indicate for you. You will not put yourself and your boss in a "embarrassing situation"

Comment: I know how difficult is to be a introvert person. But you need to fight with this. Its your right to get your payment in day, its a basic right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say to your boss.

> Hey when you get a minute can we have a quick chat in the meeting room?

Then once in the meeting room explain you didn't want to bring it up in front of your co-workers but its review time and you would like to schedule a time to do it.

Comment: Still no word. should I remind him as I been doing it every week?

Comment: have you been reminding him weekly via email or by talking to him?
if you have been sending emails, start talking to him, try to catch him early in the morning before his day gets away from him, or right when he gets back from lunch.

if you have been talking to him and sending emails.  Perhaps just approach him and be a bit more direct.  "Hey boss, do you have a minute?"  if he says yes, invite him to join you in the meeting room.  if he says no, press him for a good time.

Comment: messenger chats

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest an email.

*"Hey Boss.  I know we're supposed to have an review/raise this month but I don't see anything on the calendar yet.  Is this a meeting you set up or do you want me to do so?*

Comment: We are young company. No Calendars.

Comment: Skip the calendar then. :)

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion may come a bit extreme but either quit or stay with it. I base this off your comments: 1) you cannot talk to your boss in front of others to ask about your review, and 2) you cannot schedule anything since your company is young. It sounds rather hellish that you're in a position where you cannot even speak to your boss or schedule anything with him and you may or may not get paid on time.

Comment: Yup.  The situation sounds bizarre.

Comment: No, I love my work and people. I wouldn't think of quitting. I am introvert. Never had courage to stand up or intervene. There are times, when X say we want to talk to you, we go to meeting room and discuss.