# Dealing with late payment

Tags: salary, united-kingdom

Lately, I been getting paid late. I asked a question about it [here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/125314/how-to-follow-up-on-late-salary), but it has been 1-2 late now every month, while contract say "last date of each month and if weekend fall on the last date, the last working day". I had been bugging my manager and he follows up to his boss who is the CEO, and the reply usually is "U will get in the evening" but I have to remind.

Some might say it is a sign of bankruptcy but I do not think so, as the company is protected by [FCA](https://www.fca.org.uk/), also business is doing good. However, I do have a pay review coming up next week, which I have to follow up as it is 2 months delayed. While all this add a bit of frustration and on the second hand my payments due by lenders/bill get rejected as my account is empty and it affects my Credit Profile. It is a domino effect.

How can I make sure it won't happen again and I can focus on my work because this is a big distraction as my bill are due on X date and they don't get paid. My bank charges me overdraft and all stuff adds to the frustration.

Comment: Time to polish your CV.

Comment: Is this only happening with you, or are your colleagues getting similar delays?

Comment: @Kozaky I been asking my colleagues and they r on top of it but not sure about this month. However the CEO in lift yesterday did mention that I have to pay u which I said sure.

Comment: How big/small is this company? Is there a payroll / finance / HR team that takes care of wages? Does the CEO do all the payments themselves?

Comment: @Smock it not big. I will say its a mid startup. 5 years old.

Comment: Are you a direct employee of this company? Or a contractor?

Comment: If they are a contractor then all this advice goes out of the window, because you should have a war chest (big surplus of funds) and/or late payment insurance, and the fact you can have your contract terminated with no notice at all even if there's a notice period suggests with such financial troubles as bank fees you should *not* be contracting.  They also have no obligation to you as an individual because they are not hiring you as an individual, they are contracting the services of your company.

Comment: While what they are doing is wrong, and perhaps even actionable *in theory* your greatest priority should probably be to get your personal finances into a situation where you have *some* buffer against the unexpected, be that a problem on the payment side or an unexpected emergency expense.

Answer (score 5):

Based off your previous question and the information you have provided. You **cannot** change this company or the people running it.

I would start looking for new jobs. In the meantime keep following up with them. During your pay review you will be able to talk about any concerns also. Make **sure** you bring this up. Mention that these delayed payments are causing a knock on effect with my personal bills. State that if they are unable to pay you on time then you are going to have a problem as it's causing **very serious** personal issues.

No matter how much you like or enjoy your job, the bad credit and additional bills are **not** worth it.

**EDIT**: from adzzzUK's comment, It's not acceptable that you've paid all these penalty charges and you should seek to recover these charges from your employer. Simply give proof of the charges and ask them to refund it.

Comment: I would add that personally I don't feel that it's acceptable that you should have to pay all these penalty charges, because the late payment of your salary is the cause.  You should seek to recover these bank charges from your employer.

Comment: Agree @AdzzzUK, recover any and all charges. I had this same problem years ago when (UK) banks charged £34 for EVERY failed payment ("Direct Debit", we call them). I was getting hit for £130+ bank charges a month as a result. The company refused to refund as they were actually coming from my wife's account. I resigned shortly afterwards.

Comment: The only consideration here is I didn't read the OP's other posts and it's clear that they are a contractor.  If they were an employee rather than a contractor, this would be easy to recoup - however, I suspect difficulties may lie ahead because of the different type of working relationship.  Contractors are almost always treated worse than permanent employees!

Answer (score 2):

I worked for a company that did this very thing, though I was a remote worker and the company was based in Malta (I'm in the US). His excuses ranged anywhere from "I'm in Asia and can't access bank account" (this was the CEO speaking) to "I sent it yesterday," only to receive it weeks later.

There was a worker who hadn't been paid for 2 months (though did finally get paid). I was paid once a month and would regularly go 1.5-2 months before being paid, but he always ended up paying.

I struggled with this as well, but it became clear to me that the owner of the company didn't care about his employees, else he would've paid them all on time, without fail. The company ended up going under, even though we were told everything was fine.

You should be sending out your resumes at this point because even if the company is doing well, it appears the payments are coming from one person and that person doesn't put much stock into paying his own bills on time. If you're dealing with someone that forgets to pay his bills then you're dealing with a ticking time-bomb.

My suggestion is to get while the getting is good. I left my job and a month later, the company went under, taking all the other workers with it.

Don't believe what they're telling you about finances, even if your sales are up. That CEO could be embezzling money and using it to pay for [insert ridiculous thing here].

It's time to hit the door and leave a review on Glassdoor.